# AngularJs reference scope variable in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a simple app for demonstrational use and I have following problem: I have two objects in my controller (credentials and authServer) and I would like to reference the credentials properties in the authServer object. Both scope.credential properties are bound to input fields but they are not updated onchange in my authServer object.

I know that I can achieve this with $watch, but I'm looking for a more elegant way.

```
var app = angular.module('clientApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.credentials = {
      'username': null,
      'password' : null
    };

    $scope.authServer = {
      'url' : 'http://localhost:9000/auth', 
      'request' : {
        'grant_type': null,
        'scope': null,
        'client_id': null,
        'client_secret': null, 
        'username' : $scope.credentials.username,
        'password' : $scope.credentials.password
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: You need to reassign it to update.

Answer (score 0):

Change this portion to the below

```
$scope.authServer = {
  'url' : 'http://localhost:9000/auth', 
  'request' : {
    'grant_type': null,
    'scope': null,
    'client_id': null,
    'client_secret': null, 
    'username' : $scope.credentials.username,
    'password' : $scope.credentials.password
  }
};
```

You want to reference '$scope.credentials' because this is an object and objects are passed by references where as $scope.credentials.username are passed by value.

```
$scope.authServer = {
  'url' : 'http://localhost:9000/auth', 
  'request' : $scope.credentials
};

$scope.authServer.request['grant_type'] = null;
$scope.authServer.request['scope'] = null;
$scope.authServer.request['client_id'] = null;
$scope.authServer.request['client_secret'] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

Set `$scope.authServer` its value only when you need to use it

```
$scope.doRequest = function() {
  $scope.authServer = {
  'url' : 'http://localhost:9000/auth', 
  'request' : {
    'grant_type': null,
    'scope': null,
    'client_id': null,
    'client_secret': null, 
    'username' : $scope.credentials.username,
    'password' : $scope.credentials.password
  };
  // use $scope.authServer here
};
```

## Solution 2

Use a `$scope.$watch('credentials', function(){ $scope.authServer=/*...*/ }, true);` inside your controller

## Solution 3

(See Yang Li's answer), reference the *object* `$scope.credentials` instead of the individual properties

Comment: Thx, i thought there would be a more elegant way to do this, but I'll set both variables just right before sending it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the credentials *object*, which is a reference type. The username and password are primitives, which are value types.

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dNt8uyE7XSWF1rOd35QI?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.credentials = {
      'username': null,
      'password' : null
    };

    $scope.authServer = {
      'url' : 'http://localhost:9000/auth', 
      'request' : {
        'grant_type': null,
        'scope': null,
        'client_id': null,
        'client_secret': null, 
        'credentials': $scope.credentials
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: thx, but this wouldn't work for me since i have to keep both schemas as they are